# Objective C class to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Iam posting a NSDictionary to a JSON webservice for saving my data back to a local database. Whats the best way of converting Objective C classes to NSDictionaries?

Here is my current code, except from writing a more generic version, is this the best way/only to do this? And including `<obj/runtime.h>` is OK with apple?

```
 - (NSDictionary*)dictionaryFromContact {

        Class contactClass = [self class];
        u_int count;

        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(contactClass, &count);

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:count];

        for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(properties[i]) 
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            //Set the dicationary values from our properties
            [dict setValue:[self valueForKey:str] forKey:str];
        }
        free(properties);

        return [dict autorelease];
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class_copyPropertyList` is legit. You may consider `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` for shortcut.

If you use `Core Data` for local database, you should use `attributesByName` and `relationshipsByName`, or `propertiesByName`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) feature of [RestKit](http://restkit.org), it might do what you need.

Comment: Restkit is very difficult to implement! Plus it has lots of problems. After finally getting v0.10 to work, upgrading to v0.20 was such a pain, that I dropped it and am writing my own parser. I wouldn't recommend RestKit.